# Javascript efficient copy array into another array at index

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

In javascript, lets say I have a preallocated array of `n` items, and I have another array that I want to copy into the first array at a given starting index, the following is one way to do it:

```
let arr = new Array(25);
console.log(arr);

let arrB = Array(5).fill(1);
let insertAt = 5;
for(let ix = 0; ix < arrB.length; ix++)
  arr[ix + insertAt] = arrB[ix];
console.log(arr);
```

Is there a more efficient / standard way of doing this?

I am thinking of something equivalent to the following in C++:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/199358/

Comment: array slice? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: splice should fit your use-case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188970/the-best-performant-way-to-push-items-into-array

Comment: There are options that are more succinct, but I think you will be hard pressed to come up with something more efficient than this.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The above example is just to illustrate my point, in production I have an array of length probably up to 1 million in length , and I might need to insert say 100k entries, so efficiency is my main priority.

Comment: BTW: if you need efficiency you may be interested on perform calculations on GPU using... pure JS - and this library - [gpu.js](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js)

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency wise, I do not think there is a better way than the code you posted. You will need to go through all the items in the array that need to be copied.

I agree with others in that using `slice` is probably the standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
arr.splice(insertAt,5, ...arrB)
```

```js
let arr = new Array(25);
console.log(arr);

let arrB = Array(5).fill(1);
let insertAt = 5;

arr.splice(insertAt,5, ...arrB)
console.log(arr);
```

Following by [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements. syntax: `arr.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`. Example usage in above snippet

**UPDATE**

Indeed splice is standard way, but it is slower than for loop - I perform test to check it [**HERE**](https://jsperf.com/arr2arr/1). Splice is ~28% slower than for-loop.

If your array contains float numbers then you can use [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) or [Uint32array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array) which is almost 2x faster that `Array` (splice is not supported for chrome)

```js
let arr = new Float32Array(25);
console.log(arr);
let arrB = new Float32Array(5).fill(1);

let insertAt = 5;
for(let ix = 0; ix < arrB.length; ix++)
  arr[ix + insertAt] = arrB[ix];
console.log(arr);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I read you [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300639/860099) and make comparision with `Uint32Array` (in case if you wish to use array with integers) - it is 2x faster than normal Array - [here](https://jsperf.com/arr2arr2/1).

```js
Uint32Array.prototype.copyInto = function(arr,ix = 0) {    
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    this[ix+i] = arr[i];
  return this;
}

let a = new Uint32Array(2).fill(1);
let x = new Uint32Array(5).fill(0).copyInto(a,2);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how performance efficient this code will be (As am still a learner) but proposing it as another way of achieving such result.

```
let arr = new Array(25);
let arrB = Array(5).fill(1);
let insertAt = 5;

function copy(index) {
    if (arrB.length === 0 || index > 9) {
        return;
    }

    arr[index] = arrB.shift();
    copy(index + 1);
}

copy(insertAt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a module to make this easier:

```
const checks = require("checks"); //NB, NOT ON NPM....

(()=>{
  Array.prototype.copyInto = function(arr,ix = 0){
    if(!checks.isArray(arr))
      throw new Error("'arr' argument must be an array");
    if(!checks.isInteger(ix) || ix < 0)
      throw new Error("'ix' must be a positive integer");
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      this[ix+i] = arr[i];
    return this;
  }
})();
```

which means it can be used like this:

```
let x = Array(5).fill(0).copyInto([1,1],2);
console.log(x);
```

Not sure if this is the right approach, but it works for me.